# Outlook 365: Rule to check if a specific user is missing (and then forward the email to them)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, email-filter

I need some help with Outlook rules:

**Problem:**
Users are not attaching all invested parties to communications regarding certain topics. Example: User has problem and contacts Engineer X. Engineer Y is not in the CC or the To field, but should be.

**Desired outcome:**
Engineer Y gets a copy of the email that snubbed him, automatically sent to them.

I have most of the rules in place:

1. Look for specific words/keys
2. I must be in the TO box

The issue is I need a condition that checks if Engineer Y is not in the recipients list. 
I normally would look for a negation clause but I appear to not be able to find any in the Outlook rules.

Anyone know if either of the following exist:

1. The negation clause exists
2. There is a way to check if an email is missing a recipient

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try adding an exception in the rule, for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked swell! 

Thankfully the snubbing has stopped, so I'm not using it. I was glad to see it work though.